# What is PP_OFF?

Tags: gwt

Every single GWT example I look at contains references to `$PP_OFF`. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-4/wiki/DevGuideStyleSheets or http://khanzeeshan.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/creating-project-for-gwt-1-5-3/ for example.

What does $PP_OFF mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of defunct wiki markup. The Google Code wiki treats {{{...}}} blocks as code and attempts to pretty-print them, which doesn't always work well; $PP_OFF is, or was, an undocumented feature that's supposed to stop that happening. See http://groups.google.com/group/gwt-google-apis/msg/04ae50fdd4339294 for the only mention of this that I can find online.

You should completely ignore it wherever you see it.

(You might be wondering why it would appear on some random person's WordPress blog, which of course isn't using the Google Code wiki. The answer appears to be that the person in question just copied-and-pasted stuff from Google's documentation. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.5/tutorial/create.html if you're curious about the original source which, of course, he didn't credit.)